# setMediaTime not setting specified time on realized player

Tags: java, jmf

I've a situation where I'm creating an instance of javax.Media.player (to play audio in wav foramt) using javax.Media.Manager and I've code which looks like:-

```
  Player player = null;
  MediaLocator locator = new MediaLocator("file path to wav file");
  Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, new Boolean(true));
  try {
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(locator);
    }
    catch (CannotRealizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.addControllerListener(this);
    player.start();
    player.setMediaTime();
```

And after having an instance of player I'm invoking setMediaTime on it, the problem is that sometimes the player is updated with the time provided and sometime not.
Can anyone please suggest me that what mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got this working by tweaking my code, I obtained the player instance by

```
Manager.createPlayer(localtor)
```

and got my player realized by using busy waiting method, as soon as the player gets realized I invoke the setMediaTime method to set the audio start off set.

The reason why I was facing this problem was that, BasicPlayer from JMF API spwan a new thread if the fresh player instance is created and once the player is started and realized calling setMediaTime won't have any effect on that, basically this was more a threading issue which I overlooked.